# Getting error message for rospack depends geometry_msgs

Tags: rosmake, geometry-msgs, ros-diamondback, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i haven't been using ros for a while.
Today i tried to compile some ros nodes i create last month.

However i was getting an error message...
I figured out that it has to do something with my geometry_msgs package.

As i tried to look at the dependencies with

```
rospack depends geometry_msgs
```

i got the same error message i got for the make command:

```
[rospack] woah! expanding the dependency tree made it blow up.
There must be a circular dependency somewhere.
[rospack] circular dependency
```

i'm using diamondback-desktop-full.
I update/reinstalled it. However this didn't make anything better.

Any ideas what i'm messing up?

cheers
mimax

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11370/getting-error-message-for-rospack-depends-geometry_msgs/) by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have two packages that depend on one another anywhere in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? If you have any two packages that depend on one another, you could cause this circular dependency. In case you're curious, the output of `rospack depends geometry_msgs` on your system should look like this:

```
rosbuild
roslang
cpp_common
roscpp_traits
rostime
roscpp_serialization
rospack
roslib
xmlrpcpp
rosconsole
std_msgs
rosgraph_msgs
roscpp
rospy
rosclean
rosgraph
rosparam
rosmaster
rosout
roslaunch
rosunit
rostest
topic_tools
rosbag
rosbagmigration
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-09-29**:
mmmh.. thanks for you answer. One package in my own rospackages folder was causing problem... still don't know what exactly the problem was, since i coudl not see any circual dependencies. anyway it's working ;)